# NodeJs :- 92% chunk asset optimization TerserPlugin FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, webpack, storybook

I've following dependencies and huge set of components in react and using storybook and webpack,

```
"@storybook/react": "5.0.6",
"styled-components": "5.0.1",
"typescript": "3.5",
"webpack": "4.39.3",
"webpack-cli": "3.3.7"
```

locally everything was working fine while building storybook at remote it was continuously failing at this step, giving this error :-

```
16:19:16 <s> [webpack.Progress] 92% chunk asset optimization TerserPlugin
16:21:20 
16:21:20 <--- Last few GCs --->
16:21:20 
16:21:20 [430:0x3f22bb0]   291204 ms: Mark-sweep 1403.2 (1484.9) -> 1403.2 (1484.9) MB, 1152.6 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
16:21:20 [430:0x3f22bb0]   292437 ms: Mark-sweep 1403.2 (1484.9) -> 1403.0 (1453.9) MB, 1233.4 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
16:21:20 [430:0x3f22bb0]   293968 ms: Mark-sweep 1403.0 (1453.9) -> 1403.0 (1453.9) MB, 1531.0 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
16:21:20 
16:21:20 
16:21:20 <--- JS stacktrace --->
16:21:20 
16:21:20 ==== JS stack trace =========================================
16:21:20 
16:21:20 Security context: 0x3e34ae9a5879 <JSObject>
16:21:20     1: /* anonymous */ [/home/jenkins/workspace/FlashtoolsUikit-03-Npm-Package-Update-Storybook/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-node.js:~342] [pc=0x18aaeba69706](this=0xc21c728c209 <JSGlobal Object>,chunk=0x19b226eb79a1 <String[2]:  }>,original=0x1f48ac1ce9 <Object map = 0x3723b1482259>)
16:21:20     2: SourceNode_walk [/home/jenkins/workspace/FlashtoolsUikit-03-Npm-Package-Update...
16:21:20 
16:21:20 FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
16:21:20  1: node::Abort() [node]
16:21:20  2: 0x8c21ec [node]
16:21:20  3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [node]
16:21:20  4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
16:21:20  5: v8::internal::Factory::NewUninitializedFixedArray(int) [node]
16:21:20  6: 0xd4b153 [node]
16:21:20  7: v8::internal::Runtime_GrowArrayElements(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
16:21:20  8: 0x18aaeb5042fd
16:21:48 sh: line 1:   420 Aborted                 (core dumped) npm run build:storybook
16:21:48 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
16:21:48 npm ERR! errno 134
```

tried updating webpack (terser plugin specially) after google search but no luck, keep on getting this error continuously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After passing following node option along with other build command i.e.

```
export "NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=2000"
```

no more out of heap memory, issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am building on the Mac.
The reason is that although I have:

```
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192
```

My local Docker engine setting only has 2GB ram allowed.
After changing it to 8GB, everything works much faster.

Comment: This worked for me, although I only had to set mine to 4Gb.
FWIW I also tried changing the swap limits to no avail, it has to be memory.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue where the webpack config was a class rather then a plain javascript config which when garbage collection ran it caused the crash..

Answer (score -2):

Try this, worked for me: " ng serve --sourceMap=false "